# Original 1930 Burns & Oates "Thoughts of the Curé of Ars"

Tags: resource-request, st-john-vianney

Inside this book (page 4):

[https://www.amazon.com/Thoughts-Cure-Ars-John-Vianney/dp/089555240X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/089555240X)

one finds:

First published (presumably by Burns & Oates) in 1930 as *Thoughts of the Curé of Ars*

I have tried to find a book with this title published in 1930 without success.

It seems that Burns & Oates did publish a book in that year entitled, *Thoughts of the Curé of Ars for Every Day*---and I guess, this is probably the book alluded to in the 1984 book illustrated in the Amazon link.

It also seems that Burns & Oates published this book in both French and English.

Does anyone know if an archived copy of the 1930 book is available somewhere in either French or English (preferably French), and if so, where it may be found? (If not archived online, can anyone point me to a site where this book is available for purchase?) Thank you.

Comment: Is this the book (from 1896): https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/102218434?

Comment: @SamuelBowditch No; that is an entirely different book published by Flynn and Mahony from the one published in 1984 by TAN and so, also in 1930.

Comment: @SamuelBowditch I am looking for the French or English version of the "Thoughts" published by Burns & Oates in 1930.